# Did Proto-Indo-Europeans whisper?

Tags: proto-indo-european

I saw that Proto Indo Europeans had a word for whispering *(*kweys*). Did they whisper to each other like people do now? And, did we learn whispering from Proto Indo Europeans?

Comment: How in the world could anyone decide that based on fact? There are no anthropological field studies of Proto-Indo-European culture?

Comment: So, say, uncontacted peoples never whisper?!

Comment: Who’s “we”? I would guess that most users of this site _are_ (descendent from) Indo-Europeans. And what makes you think anyone had to learn to whisper from other peoples? Whispering is fairly universal in humans.

Answer (score 2):

The English "whisper" does not in fact have any clear cognate outside of Germanic. Thus, the Indo-European *ḱweys- is a dubious restoration, at least in the sense "whisper". None the less, there is no reason to doubt that PIE people did whisper, like all other peoples.

Comment: What about Russian [свистеть](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian) "to whistle"?

Comment: And Sanskrit *śvasiti*

Comment: @BertBarrois. Sanskrit ŚVAS means “hiss” and the like, and it points to an IE *ḱwes-, not *ḱweys-.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica. The Slavic words mean "neigh", "whistle" and the like, not "whisper".

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/wiehern

Comment: _Свистеть_ doesn't mean 'neigh'.

Comment: @Aer. Who said that it does?

Comment: Well, I don't see an unbridgeable semantic gap between "whisper", "hiss", and "whistle", they are all noises made with the mouth without using voicing. German *wiehern* is an interesting addition to the semantic field.

Comment: You wrote, 'The Slavic words...' So I made it clear that the Russian word does not mean 'neigh'. You can take it as a clarification, not as a mistake correcting.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica. I do not contest what you say about the semantic gap. It is just that the question was specifically about "whisper". I still do not see any evidence for the use of *ḱweys- for "whisper" outside of Germanic.

Comment: @fdb: I read just the other day that PCelt \*swisdeti (ref. Matasovic) AGr. σίζω (sízō), "I hiss", Russian свиста́ть reconstruct PIE \*sweysd-. This implies Ger *schwatzen*, *schwätzen* (hat mir ein Vögelchen ge-*zwitschert*), in my humble opinion. but do see *quasseln, quaddeln, quatschen* "to chat". Ger *wehen*, En *weather* can be neatly isolated, but I'd go further and try to separate the \*w, too, to isolate \*Hey-. Do you follow?